# how to separate more than 1 value in a text box with a semicolon in asp.net autocomplete textbox

Tags: c#, asp.net, ajax, ajaxcontroltoolkit

I have a text box with auto complete extender and it works fine. How can I allow the user to enter more than 1 value  by separting the first value with a semicolon(;)

```
<asp:TextBox ID="txt_to" runat="server" />

 <asp:AutoCompleteExtender ID="AutoCompleteExtender1" runat="server" TargetControlID="txt_to"
 MinimumPrefixLength="2" CompletionInterval="10" EnableCaching="true" FirstRowSelected="true" CompletionSetCount="3" UseContextKey="True" ServiceMethod="GetCompletionList" />
```

Comment: and i still think Ajax controls have long way to go up the ladder. Compare it to YUI autocomplete to know what you are missing

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As explained in the demo page [here](http://www.asp.net/ajaxLibrary/AjaxControlToolkitSampleSite/AutoComplete/AutoComplete.aspx), you should use the `DelimiterCharacters` property:

```
<asp:AutoCompleteExtender ID="AutoCompleteExtender1" runat="server"
    TargetControlID="txt_to" MinimumPrefixLength="2" CompletionInterval="10"
    EnableCaching="true" FirstRowSelected="true" CompletionSetCount="3"
    UseContextKey="True" ServiceMethod="GetCompletionList"
    DelimiterCharacters=";" />
```

Comment: How to get the value in server side code, should I trim the string to get the values? or how is it done

Comment: The autocomplete extender only sets the value of the `<input>` element it extends, the rest is up to you. So, you should `Split()` the element's value on the semicolon character and iterate over the resulting substrings, possibly `Trim()`ming them in the process.